# Не масштабируется текст при уменьшении окна браузера

Tags: шрифты, html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте. Есть такой стиль, применяемый к тексту:

```
    #slogan{
    font-family: Marianna, 'Marianna';
    font-size: 2.9em;
    color: #666666;
    line-height:1em;
    width:30%;    
    padding-left: 63%;
   }
```

Сколько в Интернете читал, везде пишут, что надо поставить em, и всё будет хорошо. Но я поставил, а текст всегда так и остаётся одного размера(
В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать либо единицы измерения текста [vw и vh](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/), либо плагины типа [TextFit](http://plugins.jquery.com/textFit/). Самый простой и наиболее часто применяемый способ регулировать размер текста в медиазапросах.